# In typescript is there a way to replicate the class implements functionality when using functions?

Tags: typescript

given the following interface

```js
interface Foo {
  a: () => string
}
```

it is possible to implement a class that extends this functionality

```js
class Bar implements Foo {
  a: jest.fn(() => 'hello');
}

const bar = new Bar();
bar.a.mockImplementation(() => 'b') // <-- typescript does not complain here
```

In the above code typescript ensures that property 'a' is implemented on Bar but recognizes that it is a jest.Mock type. However, I'm not sure how to replicate this using only functions.

```js
function newFoo (): Foo {
  return {
    a: jest.fn(() => 'a')
  }
}

const foo = newFoo();
foo.a.mockImplementation(() => 'b') // <-- mockImplementation does not exist on type '() => string'
```

### Context

In case I'm going about this the wrong way, the reason for wanting to use a function over a class is that closures provide better encapsulation (ie even private properties of a class can be identified by Object.keys()) and a third-party lib complains when unexpected properties are present on an object.

Comment: Regarding your comment about private properties, this does not seem to be the case? `Object.keys(new class { #private; public; }())` returns `['public']`.

Comment: ahhh thanks!! was using the private modifier rather than '#' had no idea this was part of the syntax

Comment: Does this question depend on jest? If so it should probably be tagged as such. If not then could you remove your example code's dependency on it so it can be a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?